# How to remove category name from url in opencart 2.x?

Tags: php, seo, opencart

I want to remove category name from url in my opencart site.
I searched for solution at many places. some are suggesting to replace `$url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];` with `$url = '/' . $query->row['keyword'];`
in seo_url.php but the problem is still not solved when i select a product from category menu it is still showing category name in url. How to remove that category name in opencart 2.x i am using opencart 2.1
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not going to be able to without heavy modification. That modification is going to require a knowledge of the OpenCart framework that goes beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
Opencart stores another copy of files in `system/storage/modification/catelog` folder.
If i delete or rename `seo_url.php` file from there. then it starts acception my changes.

Otherwise it will not accept any modification in `seo_url.php` file.